# Video Not Loading in Three.js

Tags: javascript, video, three.js

I have a Three.js project that tries to load four videos (about 40MB each) and place them on a simple model of a room.

It works fine when I use 4 small videos, but when I use the bigger videos the sound loads but the video doesn't.

I'm probably doing something stupid or repetitive... the page is here...

https://googledrive.com/host/0Bznu7JgRtB5CLVVfb2Zub05YdVE/Three.js/cliffords.html

Comment: are all the videos of size powers of two?

Comment: Thanks yes. I have worked out what it was... I was making the movies using MoviePy and using the mpg4 codec. When I used H.264, they worked.


    clip1 = (VideoFileClip(movie_file))
    wall1 = crop(clip1, x1=0, y1=0, x2=s, y2=h) #Wall 1
    wall1.write_videofile("wall1.mp4", codec="libx264")

Comment: They were yes, and to be doubly sure, they were factors of four. I found the problem in the end to be one of encoding and running them through a tool, maybe VLC, fixed it.